# Difference between semiclassical QFT and QFT

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform, shors-algorithm

In papers, one of them being *An Experimental Study of Shor's Factoring Algorithm on IBM Q* is stated that replacing QFT with the semiclassical QFT *(Kitaev's approach)* reduces the needed number of qubits to solve a given problem with Shor's algorithm. Other than using a different approach - *measuring one qubit of the period register each time contrary to the approach where multiple qubits are used* is there a mathematical difference between sc-QFT and QFT?

More precisely, my question is: if QFT is mathematically described as

$$| x \rangle \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{y=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi ixy}{N}\right) | y\rangle,$$

how does the equation for sc-QFT look like?

Comment: Did you try to read this one: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9511007.pdf? https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0001066.pdf? They are references numner 12 and 13 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.08852.pdf

Comment: Yes and all I can see is the equation I have stated rewritten in different forms. All I can conclude is that the sc-QFT is just another approach and not a different mathematical operator compared to QFT. However, as I'm not 100% sure of this I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semi-classical QFT only behaves the same as the QFT *if you are immediately measuring the QFT's output*. A mathematical description of the *unitary effect* of the QFT isn't going to work, because the semi-classical QFT isn't a unitary operation. It's a frequency space measurement operation.

You need to describe the semi-classical QFT in terms of the probability distribution of measurement results (as a function in the input state). You can also describe QFT+measure in this way, and confirm that their descriptions in terms of probability distribution are equal.